# Sublime Text 3 Highlighting Jquery Angular Syntax Issue

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

After updating from Sublime Text 2 to Sublime Text 3, I have experienced some issues with the highlighting of variables mostly in the case of Angular or JQuery elements no longer having a highlight of pink (using Monokai theme; default)

Has anyone experienced this issue or know a way to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These variables have, with the normal javascript syntax, the scope `variable.other.dollar.js`. The scope `variable` and `variable.other` have no highlighting in the monokai colorscheme. If you want to add a highlighting on your own, you can just modify the colorscheme. To do this I would recommend the [Package Resource Viewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer). Just press `ctrl+shift+p` and select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` and navigate to the monokai colorscheme. This will open the colorscheme xml file.
If you save it, it will not change the existing one (which is read only in a zip folder), but create it in your Packages folder. This colorscheme will shadow the existing one. Add the following entry at a reasonable position and the variables should be highlighted pink:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>JQuery Variable</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>variable.other.dollar.js</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#FF90FF</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

In general you can use the [ScopeHunter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeHunter) to retrieve the scope and adapt the colorscheme to fit your requirements.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!